# "have liked"/"have been liking"/"had liked"/"had been liking"

Tags: difference, tense, progressive-aspect, perfect-aspect

1. I have liked you since childhood.
2. I have been liking you since childhood.
3. I had liked you since childhood.
4. I had been liking you since childhood.

What is the difference between the above sentences?

Answer (score 0):

I have liked you since childhood is the best option, because "to like" is not used in the progressive form. It is a so-called non- continuous verb. It means you started liking the person in your childhood and you still like them in the present. This tense is called present perfect.

The same goes for I had liked you since childhood, only here the situation is set in the past. You still liked someone at a moment in the past, not the present. This tense is called past perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The difference are:

a) 2 and 4 are not idiomatic in British English, or (I'm pretty certain) in American English - we simply don't use *like* with the progressive unless we're talking about a sequence of separate events (*I'm liking each episode of that show more and more*).

It may be different in Indian English, as I know that progressive forms are used more there.

b) 3 is appropriate in a context where we have a temporal focus in the past, and we are looking backward from there. This is common in narrative, but less common in speech.
The only context I can think of where that sentence is likely in speech is if are talking about a meeting or establishing a new relationship that took place in the past, so the sentence is relative to that event.